# Issue with using MultiLineString in Leaflet Animated Marker Plugin

Tags: leaflet, geojson, animation

This response on image below is coming from Geoserver as MultiLineString and I restructured it to LineString like on image because Animation plugin doesn`t support MultiPolyline json structure and because response has coordinates as lng, lat and I need lat, lng as Leaflet defines. This structure on image works nice with animation plugin.

Since [Leaflet Animated Marker Plugin](https://github.com/openplans/Leaflet.AnimatedMarker) I use doesn't support MultiLineStrings I had to structure it as LineString. It accepts this LineString structure but coordinates are mixed after I apply coordsToLatLngs static method.
That makes my marker not appearing on first position and jumping back and forth. Until this line of code coordinates are in right order, as defined in SQL View on Geoserver and I could check it and prove in DB and in QGIS

This is view on Geoserver:

```
SELECT pgr.seq AS seq,
   pgr.edge AS edge,
   e.id AS id,
   SUM(e.distance) AS distance,
   st_linemerge(st_union(e.geom)) AS geom
  FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target,onewayNum as cost, r_cost as 
   reverse_cost FROM parking.n_streets_noded',%source%,%target%, true) AS 
   pgr, parking.n_streets_noded  AS e 
 WHERE pgr.edge = e.id
 GROUP BY  pgr.seq, e.geom,e.name,e.type, pgr.seq, pgr.edge,e.id
 ORDER by pgr.seq
```

[image]

This is function with ajax call:

```
function getFinalRoute(){
var urlRoute = `${geoserver}/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&
typeName=xxx:shortestpath&viewparams=source:${source};target:${targetN || targetE}&outputformat=application/json
&srsName=EPSG:4326`;
var routeLayer = L.geoJSON(null);
var flippedCoords;
$.ajax({
    url: urlRoute,
    async: false,
    success: function(response){    
        console.log(response)
                var routeArr = response.features;
                var coordsArr = Object.keys(routeArr).map(key => {
                    return routeArr[key]
                })

                var xxy = coordsArr.map(function(feature){
                var obj = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
                    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
                        return obj[key];                        
                    })
                })
   //code above gives me coordinates in perfect order but after applying this method below their order mixes up
                var flipCoor = L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(xxy,1);

                var flippedCoor = flipCoor.sort().map(function(obj){
                    return Object.values(obj).sort().map(values => {
                        return Object.values(values)
                    })
                }) 

              var myArray = [].sort().concat(...flippedCoor);

                console.log(myArray);

                var multiLineString = L.polyline(myArray);
                var secondAnimated = L.animatedMarker(multiLineString.getLatLngs(), {
                                        distance: 100,
                                        interval: 500,
                                        iconSize:[16,16],
                                        iconAnchor: [7, 16],
                                        //autostart: false,
                                        icon: pulsingIcon
                                    });

                map.addLayer(secondAnimated);
                routeLayer = L.geoJSON(response)

            }

    })      
    map.addLayer(routeLayer);       
};
```

Comment: You say «it doesnt give me any error response but it does give me bugs»... what do you mean by *bugs* exactly? Are there any errors on your JS console?

Comment: Not a single error in console, but other layers become useles and they act wierd as soon as I zoom in/out @IvanSanchez

Comment: One thing is definitely true: `Leaflet.AnimatedMarker` plugin does not know how to work with MultiPolylines (tested). You have to animate each segment separately.

Comment: damn, i knew it...are you aware of any other plugin that could handle this in Leaflet? Meaning to animate it separately I would just load LineStrings instead MultiLineStrings? I think I did it once when all of them appeared at once and were animating each their "own space"...Than it will be tricky to merge them somehow.Zivio! @TomazicM

Comment: I wouldn't search for another plugin. I suppose you want animation to go to the next line segment when it finishes the previous one. You can use `onEnd` option to start animation of next segment when animation of the current one ends.

Comment: I haven´t used onEnd because I managed to get LineString with all coordinates and single marker appears and animates over them...the problem now is that coordinates are not in right order...i updated my question and code @TomazicM

Comment: You completely changed the question and so now nobody knows what was the original one. And this can go on ad infinitum ... One of the basic policies of this site is: one question per question. If you have new question, please post it as a separate question (and revert this one to the original question).

Comment: I am just trying to solve my issue and once when solved I would explain the path I was on, and that one was wrong. Sorry but I didnt read basic policy of this site.Apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is stuck with **Animation plugins in Leaflet when using MultiLine features** it is good to know that most of them will not accept such structure of JSON/GeoJSON where values, in this case coordinates, are nested a bit deeper when comparing with simple LineString features whose structure is like Array of Objects and in my case looks so:

```
[{lat,lng},{lat,lng}{lat,lng}...]
```

Such structure and order of coordinates in Leaflet will allow getLatLngs() method in Animation Marker plugin to do it´s work even tough our data comes from server as MultiLineString.

My second issue along with trying to de-structure response was jQuery **ajax** call. I was using single call to create an object from response and to "manipulate" response and use it for Animation marker creation at the same time. I guess this is not recommendable so hopefully someone here can confirm it and explain it better. When I was working with **single call** **response** my coordinates would mix up somehow and I would never reach desired LineString structure with coordinates in right order.

Therefore I split the call in two, one for creating route layer, other for creating Animation Marker and got result I wanted right away.

```
function getFinalRoute(){
    var urlRoute = `${geoserver}/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&
    typeName=xxx:shortestpath&viewparams=source:${source};target:${targetN || targetE}&outputformat=application/json`;
    var routeLayer = L.geoJSON(null);
    $.ajax({
        url: urlRoute,
        async: false,
        success: function(response){    
                    routeLayer = L.geoJSON(response)
                    goPark(urlRoute);
            }   
        })      
        map.addLayer(routeLayer);       
    };

function goPark(urlRoute){
    $.ajax({
        url: urlRoute,
        asnyc: false,
        success: function(data) {
            coordinatesArr = data.features
            console.log(coordinatesArr);
            var coordsArr = Object.keys(coordinatesArr).map(key => {
                return coordinatesArr[key]
            });
            xxy = coordsArr.map(function(feature){
                var obj = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
                return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
                    return obj[key];
                })
            });
     /*line below ensures flipping coordinates to LatLng with MultiLineString 
       structure where xxy is array and 1 allows to reach nested value. This 
       value can be decreased as well as increased depending how deep the 
       value is nested*/
            var flipCoor = L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(xxy, 1);
            var flippedCoor = flipCoor.map(function(obj){
                return Object.values(obj)
                })
            var myArray = [].sort().concat(...flippedCoor);
            var lineString = L.polyline(myArray);
            var secondAnimated = L.animatedMarker(lineString.getLatLngs(), {
                                    distance: 500,
                                    interval: 50,
                                    iconSize:[14,14],
                                    iconAnchor: [7, 14],
                                    //autostart: false,
                                    icon: pulsingIcon,
                                    onEnd: function(){
                                        alert("Parked")
                                    }
                                    });

            map.addLayer(secondAnimated);

        }
    })
}
```

Slovenac thanks for revealing important information in comments section @TomazicM :)